# google visualization getColumnId

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a dataTable with several columns. I'm building a chart from a view of this dataTable. When an item from the legend of the chart is clicked I'd like to get the column of the underlying dataTable.

**Code:**

```
var score_select = google.visualization.events.addListener(score_chart, 'select', function(){
        var chrt = score_chart.getChart().getSelection()[0].column;//I'm using a chartWrapper
        var dt = score_chart.getDataTable().getColumnId(chrt);
        var dt_check = score_chart.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
        alert(dt);

        \\ alert(dt_check) returns proper number of columns
    });
```

**Problem:**

The column number referred to by `chrt` is equal to the column number of the view **NOT** the column number of the underlying dataTable. By this I mean, if the dataTable has 10 columns and the view of the dataTable used by `score_chart` has only 2 columns `chrt` will return either 1 or 2 regardless of what columns from the dataTable were used in the view. This is causing getColumnId(...) to return a column different from that which I would like.

Any advice would be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your view is specified in the ChartWrapper's `view` parameter, you need to reference the `view.columns` array to get the column index reference to the underlying DataTable.  Also, since the `select` event fires when users deselect an element, it is possible that the array of selected elements is empty, which would cause this line to throw an error:

```
var chrt = score_chart.getChart().getSelection()[0].column;
```

so you need to test the length of the array (and possibly iterate over all array elements if multi-select is enabled in your chart).  The code should look like this:

```
var score_select = google.visualization.events.addListener(score_chart, 'select', function(){
    var selection = score_chart.getChart().getSelection();
    if (selection.length) {
        var chrt = selection[0].column;
        var dt = score_chart.getDataTable().getColumnId(chrt);
        var dt_check = dt.getNumberOfColumns();

        var view = score_chart.getView();
        var dtColumnIndex = view.columns[chart];

        alert('The selected column is ' + dt.getColumnLabel(dtColumnIndex));
    }
});
```

This assumes that `view.columns` contains just column references - if it contains calculated columns, you have to decide what you want to do with those.